Playwright Screenshots do not show Auth view Despite Successful Token Retrieval
Problem
I'm writing Playwright tests for my React application, which uses JWT for authentication. In my test for the signed-in landing page, I'm able to successfully retrieve access and refresh tokens, and even take screenshots. However, the test fails to actually sign in the user. I believe this is because the test is not properly utilizing the CurrentUserContext.
Code
Here's the relevant part of my Playwright test (frontend/playwright/signed-in-landing-page.spec.js). The part that doesn't achieve expected results is await page.screenshot({...}); at the end
see full test here. Every step appears to work until screenshot.
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

test.describe('Signed-in Landing Page', () => {
  test('desktop', async ({ page }) => {
    // Navigates to sign-in page
    await page.goto(`${BASE_URL}/signin`);

    // Fills in credentials and submit
    await page.fill('input[name="username"]', 'user');
    await page.fill('input[name="password"]', 'qwerqwer*');
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

    // Waits for navigation and network idle
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');

    // Logs localStorage contents
    const localStorageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const data = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);
        data[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
      return data;
    });
    console.log('localStorage contents:', localStorageData);

    // Verifies user is signed in
    const accessToken = await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
    console.log('Access token:', accessToken);

    if (accessToken) {
      // Check for an authenticated element
      const signOutElement = await page.locator('text=Sign out').count();
      console.log('Sign out element count:', signOutElement);
      
      if (signOutElement === 0) {
        console.error('Sign out element not found');
        const pageContent = await page.content();
        console.log('Page content:', pageContent);
      } else {
        await expect(page.locator('text=Sign out')).toBeVisible();
      }
    }

    // Take a screenshot. FAIL. The screenshot does not show Auth view as expected.
    await page.screenshot({
      path: `screenshots/signed-in-landing-page-desktop.png`,
      fullPage: false
    });
  });
});

setup tests confirmed as working
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080');
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Odyssey/);


  await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');

  // Takes a screenshot, returns the website in logged out view as expected
  await page.screenshot({
    path: `screenshots/setup-confirmed.png`,
    fullPage: false
  });

});

Playwright config file
// @ts-check
const { defineConfig, devices } = require('@playwright/test');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: './playwright',
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI, 
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined, 
  reporter: [['list'], ['json', { outputFile: 'test-results.json' }]],
  outputDir: 'screenshots',
  use: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    screenshot: 'on',
    headless: true,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      },
    },
  ],
  webServer: {
    command: 'python3 manage.py runserver',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    timeout: 120 * 1000
  },
});

Expected Behavior
After successfully retrieving the access token and refresh token, a screenshot should appear of the logged in view.
Actual Behavior
The test successfully retrieves the access token and refresh token, and can take screenshots. However, it fails to show the logged in view in the screenshot
Questions

Am I missing any crucial steps in the authentication process that
would prevent the user from being fully signed in?

Could there be any issues with how the tokens are being stored or
used that might prevent the sign-in from completing?


usage
ideal setup is gitpod IDE.
in terminal 1 run the server

run python3 manage.py runserver

in terminal 2 run the frontend

go to cd frontend
run npm start

in terminal 3 run the tests

go to cd frontend
npx install playwright --with-deps
xvfb-run npx playwright test [test-name here]

Other info
Playwright version: 1.47.0
React version: 17.0.2
Node.js version: 16.0
Operating System: Windows
Full Repository: http://github.com/lmcrean/odyssey-api
Any insights or suggestions on how to screenshot Auth pages in my Playwright tests would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I don't know what the deal with CurrentUserContext is but this test shouldn't mess with any of that. You want to treat your app as a blackbox. It's just a simple form submit, with the right credentials. The question is if they are correct and if the user exists. You take the screenshot after the form is sent and (supposedly) processed; so what's on the screenshot?

Or even simpler, using the same app instance as you do for the PW test: what happens when you log in with those credentials?

Please ask one question per question. Fully agree with the sentiment that Playwright should not care about React or context. Accessing local storage is also dubious--try to act like the user would. Click buttons, navigate pages, fill out forms. The user is not going to run JS in the console and mess with state or local storage, so neither should your PW tests.

Thanks for honest feedback, I have for now updated the post to focus more on screenshotting auth pages in playwright. I continue to work on this and will update with more debugging steps as I go along.

I was able to resolve this issue by updating playwright config, simplifying the test
It's mainly worth noting that I made some adjustments to the Playwright configuration file (playwright.config.js), Adding headless: true. Ensure your configuration is set up correctly, particularly the baseURL, use settings, and webServer configuration. (it was actually edited into original answer above as I was debugging).
Here's the working test - it correctly screenshots in auth state and edited out unnecessary elements.
As a junior I can't offer much more explanation of why it's working now, but did want to leave the working code for others -- being able to screenshot in auth state is such a valuable asset for documentation.
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';

test.describe('Sign-in Process', () => {
  test('desktop view', async ({ page }) => {
    // Set viewport to desktop size
    await page.setViewportSize({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

    // Navigate to the sign-in page
    await page.goto(`${BASE_URL}/signin`);
    console.log(`Navigated to ${page.url()}`);

    // Take a screenshot before signing in
    await page.screenshot({
      path: 'screenshots/signin-page-before-login.png',
      fullPage: false
    });

    // Fill in the login form
    await page.fill('input[name="username"]', 'testuser');
    await page.fill('input[name="password"]', 'password*');

    // Click the sign-in button and wait for navigation
    await Promise.all([
      page.click('button[type="submit"]'),
      page.waitForNavigation(),
    ]);

    console.log('Login attempted');

    // Check if redirected to home page
    expect(page.url()).toBe(`${BASE_URL}/`);
    console.log('Redirected to home page');

    // Check localStorage for access token
    const accessToken = await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
    if (accessToken) {
      console.log('Access token found in localStorage');
    } else {
      console.warn('Warning: No access token found in localStorage');
    }

    // Log localStorage contents
    const localStorageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const data = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);
        data[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
      return data;
    });
    console.log('localStorage contents:', localStorageData);

    // wait for idle network
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');

    // Take a screenshot after signing in
    await page.screenshot({
      path: 'screenshots/home-page-after-login.png',
      fullPage: false
    });

    console.log('Test completed for desktop view');
  });
});

